# Racket Programming ;Write a recursive function to compute the summation sum( x^2, x=1..n

Tags: racket

;Write a recursive function to compute the summation sum( x^2, x=1..n)
;You must write a recursive function.
;If you use any iterative commands (for/loop/sum/etc you will receive a 0)

I'm stuck on this

```lisp
(define (expo base x)
  (cond ((or (= base 1) (= x 0)) 1)
        (else (* base (expo base (- x 1)))))
```

I wrote this but its not right

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but is only missing a bracket at the end. You will see an error `expected a ) to close` ( `possible cause: indentation suggests a missing )` when you are missing a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

If n equal 5. You want see this: 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 55

```
#lang racket

(define (summation from-n to-n fn)
  (local [(define (aux n)
            (if (< n from-n)
                0
                (+ (fn n) (aux (- n 1)))))]
    (aux to-n)))

(define (1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2 n)
  (summation 1 n sqr))

(define (1+2+3+...+n n)
  (summation 1 n identity))

;;; TEST
(1+2+3+...+n 100) ; 5050
(1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2 5) ; 55
```